# How to write ApScheduler logs into a file?

Tags: python, logging, apscheduler

I am using python's apscheduler for running my code periodically. Even my code runs good for some time, it crashes after a while and I cannot see any log output.  I am looking a way to output scheduler logs into file.

This is my code;

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='TwitterBot/SchedulerLog.txt')
#logging.basicConfig()

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()  
scheduler.add_job(whole_run, 'interval', hours=1)  
#scheduler.print_jobs()
scheduler.start()
```

Could provide some hints?

Answer (score 1):

This ought to do it:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='TwitterBot/SchedulerLog.txt', level=logging.INFO)
```

Comment: did not work. Is it something related with Ipython Notebook, do you think ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you elaborated a little. "Did not work" does not give me much to go on. Ditto with "it crashes". And how about trying without ipython?

Comment: Right. It was not printting out something to the file before, even so after your addition.

Comment: I am trying native python instead of ipython

Comment: I tried your script and it did print quite a number of lines. I of course added the proper imports, implemented `whole_run()` as an empty function and changed `hours=1` to `seconds=1`.